# Lazy Image Drawing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, appkit

I have an object that needs to draw into a graphic context on demand, however, the content needs time to render and might not be available when the objects draw method is invoked.

How is this generally accomplished? Store a reference to the graphics context or view that requested drawing and draw it there delayed when the objects internal representation is completely rendered?

Or are there other standard cocoa mechanisms to handle this (for instance `NSImage` does lazy drawing when initialized with a `NSURL`)?

Clarifications:

---

- I am on MacOS, not iOS
- Using some `NSView`s `-setNeedsDisplay:` is not the answer I am looking for (`NSImage` doesn't rely on `-setNeedsDisplay:`)

Comment: Please explain why you are so set against calling `setNeedsDisplay:` That's just how a view signals that it is ready to be drawn. Either you're going to call it, or the view is going to do it on its own when you change one of its ivars.

Comment: Because I want to know how `NSImage` handles this without using a view reference and `-setNeedsDisplay:`.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to address this in an update to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into using [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1); either an `NSInvocationOperation`, if you have a specific object doing the rendering, or `NSBlockOperation`, if the rendering is simple enough to fit into a single function.

If you can start rendering before you actually get to your view's `drawRect:`, then do that (maybe your app delegate starts the process right at launch). Otherwise, check in the `drawRect:` whether the content is available yet; if not, start the operation and continue with the other drawing. When the rendering object finishes its work, it will probably either post a notification or, if you give it a reference back to the view, call `setNeedsDisplay:`

Along the lines of your last sentence, you could also consider your rendering object being able to return a partially-rendered image. I'm not certain of the nature of your rendering, but it may be possible to get the results at certain points (the end of every n loops, or every n lines of pixels), stuff that into a separate `NSImage` of the same size as the final image (padding at the end if necessary), and make this partial image available to the view for drawing.

UPDATE: An `NSImage` doesn't "rely on" `setNeedsDisplay:` or having a view reference because it doesn't represent a piece of the screen. All it does is contain the data for an image; it can only draw itself *inside* a view, which is then "displayed" -- actually painted on the screen. When you use `initByReferencingURL:`, it stores the URL, and then when another object (like a view that contains the image and needs to be displayed) asks it for its contents, it does what it would've done if you had used `initWithURL:`, which is open the file and read its contents into memory. It doesn't *draw* lazily, though; it only draws *into* the view that wants it, *when* that view is drawing.

Subclassing `NSImage` to implement your own lazy loading or lazy rendering may not be easy; it uses helper classes that I believe are part of a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20-TPXREF141), which is why I suggest having a "renderer" object which contains and returns an `NSImage`.

MORE:

A custom view's `drawRect`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    NSLog(@"Entered: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    // Use a nice big image of the Milky Way -- this is about 5MB
    NSImage * lazyImage = [[[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingURL:
                            [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.eso.org/public/archives/images/original/milkyway.jpg"]]
                           autorelease];
    NSLog(@"Image instantiated.");
    [lazyImage drawInRect:[self bounds] fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
    NSLog(@"Image drawn");  // 2 minutes later; sometimes 3 in my testing
    [[NSColor yellowColor] set];
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSInsetRect([self bounds], 4, 4)] stroke];
    NSLog(@"Bezier path drawn; exiting drawRect.");
}
```

The log output from this; notice that the instantiation is very quick, but the loading and drawing takes two minutes, during which nothing is drawn and the app does nothing else (spinning beach ball):

```
2011-04-27 21:33:00.899 SetNeedsDisplay[80162:a0b] Entered: drawRect:
2011-04-27 21:33:00.901 SetNeedsDisplay[80162:a0b] Image instantiated.
2011-04-27 21:34:57.911 SetNeedsDisplay[80162:a0b] Image drawn.
2011-04-27 21:34:57.912 SetNeedsDisplay[80162:a0b] Bezier path drawn; exiting drawRect.
```

Comment: Note that I am talking about MacOS; I didn't even realize Wolfgang's suggestion was for iOS.

Comment: The problem is, `NSImage` does lazy drawing even when you initialize it with an `NSURL` that references a file that first has to be downloaded from the internet. And it doesn't block the drawing method doing it (as far as I could tell). But I'll accept your answer for now.

Comment: @Erik: Lazy drawing means "only draws at the last possible moment", not "doesn't draw until it has all the data it needs to do so". It's _not_ lazy drawing. It doesn't have anywhere to draw _to_ on its own. It's _loading_ lazily; not until it's asked to draw. You'd have to post your code for me to know exactly what you're talking about, but if you try to draw an `NSImage` that was created with `initByReferencingURL:` it most certainly _will_ block a drawing method until it loads; see the further update to my answer.

Comment: Alright, I said I wasn't sure but it always *seemed* non blocking to me. But I'll take your word for it :).

Comment: @Erik: don't take my word: measure! ;) That's why I posted that code. And more important than me being right, is: I hope this actually helped you solve your problem.

Comment: @Erik: it seems non-blocking if it's fast enough -- small enough image and big enough internet connection -- and if that's _guaranteed_ to be the case, then do it that way, but you can look into `NSOperation` to make it actually non-blocking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fond of the EGOImageView class for these purposes. It's really easy to use and includes some nice bonuses as will, e.g. a caching mechanism.

Read more about EGOImageView here (includes a download link from Github):

http://developers.enormego.com/view/what_if_images_on_the_iphone_were_as_easy_as_html

Comment: The image view seems to handle it with a callback, to invoke `-setNeedsDisplay:` on the view when the download is finished. I hoped for a more general solution (like the `NSImage` drawing I mentioned).